# Memory allocation and the call stack in scheme

Tags: memory-management, scheme, callstack

When Scheme code is run by the computer, how does it set up and use the stack frame? Moreover, how does Scheme do its memory management?

For instance, if I were to run the following code in scheme

```
(define add_func x
    (lambda (y) (+ x y))

(map (add_func 2) (cdr (list 1 2 3)))
```

Then where is the function returned by add_func stored in memory. Is add_func stored on the stack? Also, is (list 1 2 3) stored in the same stack frame as (cdr (list 1 2 3))? Does every () denote a new stack frame?

Comment: None of this is specified by the standard(s) and implementations vary. You can find three different implementation strategies for Scheme in R. Kent Dybvig's [dissertation](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/~dyb/papers/3imp.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scheme does not specify specific memory management strategies or layouts. In particular, it is possible to implement Scheme to allocate *all* call frames on the heap and not use a call stack. In fact, using the heap for call frames makes it easier to implement continuations.

Your `add_func` (which I'll hereafter refer to as `add-func` in line with the conventional Scheme naming style) is not defined correctly. I presumed that you meant this instead:

```
(define (add-func x)
  (lambda (y) (+ x y)))
```

Although Scheme does not specify how things are stored in memory, the procedure returned by `add-func` is most likely stored in the heap, and not associated with any particular call frame.